# Dividir un Data Frame de manera automática con R

Tags: r, dataframe, google-api

tengo un data frame con 2 columnas y 6,000 filas (llamado data). Las 2 columnas son datos de latitud y longitud de una ruta por carretera, pero como los datos del GPS no son precisos necesito ajustarlos a las carreteras. Para poder hacer esto, utilizo la API de Google, concretamente la función google_nearestRoads, pero antes debo dividir mi dataframe en 60 data frames ya que esta función no puede procesar más de 100 datos (estos data frames los he llamado data1, data2, etc.). Luego tengo que volver a unir estos 60 data frames en uno, que he llamado coordenadas. De momento lo he hecho de la siguiente manera (a modo de ejemplo tan solo pongo 2 de los 60 data frames):

```
data1 <- data[1:99,]
ajuste1<-google_nearestRoads(data1, key = key, simplify = T)
lat1<-ajuste1$snappedPoints$location$latitude
lon1<-ajuste1$snappedPoints$location$longitude
coordenadas1<-data.frame(lat1,lon1)%>%
  rename(Latitud=lat1,Longitud=lon1)

data2 <- data[100:199,]
ajuste2<-google_nearestRoads(data2, key = key, simplify = T)
lat2<-ajuste2$snappedPoints$location$latitude
lon2<-ajuste2$snappedPoints$location$longitude
coordenadas2<-data.frame(lat2,lon2)%>%
  rename(Latitud=lat2,Longitud=lon2)

coordenadas<-rbind(coordenadas1,coordenadas2)
```

Sería posible hacer esto mediante un loop o de alguna manera para que se automatice y no tener que hacerlo uno a uno.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, hay que dividir en partes el `data.frame` original, por ejemplo usando `split()`:

```
n <- 100
filas <- nrow(data)
lista <- split(data,
               rep(1:ceiling(filas/n), each=n, length.out=filas))
```

No usé tu solución por que falla si el número de filas no es múltiplo de 100. `split()` nos deja una lista, por lo que solo nos resta recorrerla y hacer lo que tengas que hacer con cada parte:

```
for (i in 1:length(lista)) {
  
  # Extraemos el df de la lista
  df <- lista[[i]]
  
  # Hacemos lo que tengamos que hacer con los datos del df
  
  # Pisamos con el nuevo df la lista
  lista[[i]] <- df  
}
```

Finalmente, con la lista ya modificada, para unir todas las partes, podemos usar `do.call()` que permite invocar una función por cada elemento de la lista, de esta forma automatizas las llamadas a `rbind` que intentaste con solo dos porciones de datos.

```
# Unimos los df individuales un uno solo
do.call(rbind, lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido una parte. usando

```
split( data, trunc( 1:(nrow(data)-1 )/100 ) )
```

he obtenido una lista de 60 listas. Ahora necesitaría transformarla en 60 dataframes para poder aplicar la función google_nearestRoads.

Alguna idea?

Gracias

Comment: Si tenés una nueva pregunta, redactala como tal. La sección de respuestas es _solo para respuestas_. Podés crear la nueva pregunta y mencionar la actual como referencia.